# Troubles with pyplot.bar legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, legend

I'm having troubles introducing a legend in this chart. Can someone help me? I can plot the chart but everytime I try to apply a legend it doesn't work..

```
flags=['0','1','2','3','4','5']

df_stress_flagged.FLAG.value_counts()

4    265
2    177
5    121
3     84
Name: FLAG, dtype: int64

stress_flag_count=[0,0,177,84,265,121]
plt.bar(flags,
    stress_flag_count,
    color=['cyan', 'blue', 'violet', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']
)
plt.title('Stress count')
```

Comment: You don't provide [labels that can be used for the legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-legend-guide-py) and you don't initiate the legend generation with `plt.legend()`. What should the legend show?

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad, forgot them

0=baseline 
1=boredom 
2=relax  
3=active state 
4=low stress 
5=high stress. 

I tried using plt.legend() but, even if the syntax was correct, it didn't appear anything in the chart

Comment: But that would be the xticklabels. You could directly plot them `plt.bar(["baseline",...,"high stress"],  stress_flag_count,...)` As I said, you did not provide matplotlib with legend keys and handles - there is nothing in your code that suggests how you want to map bar colors to labels for a legend.

Comment: Problem solved, thank u very much!

Comment: Also note that a legend often isn't helpful in this situation. It is much friendlier towards the plot's reader to directly put the names into the x tick labels with perhaps additional information in bar labels.